# Example to implement TimePicker in Android DialogFragment in Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-widget

How to implement TimePicker in Android 3.0 . I am showing a dialog which implemented DialogFragment . In that DialogFragment if I click a button I need to display timepicker.
I am not able to implement this in Android 3.0. Can anyone provide me source to implement time picker in Android 3.0 DialogFragment.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2):

1. Add dialog preference
2. Place TimePicker control in the dialog
3. Refresh preference when date/time picked

Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html):

Also, install Code samples for SDK 11 (Honeycomb 3.0). There is ApiDemos project there which contains few examples  of different DialogFragments. There is everything you need.